# Prove (p → ¬ q) → ¬ (p ∧ q) in Lean4

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, proof, lean

I get as far as this

```
theorem problem_2 : (p → ¬ q) → ¬ (p ∧ q) := by
   intro hp 
   intro hpw
```

which gets me to ⊢ False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Not p`, or `¬p`, is the negation of `p`. It is defined to be `p → False`, so if your goal is `¬p` you can use `intro h` to turn the goal into `h : p ⊢ False`, and if you have `hn : ¬p` and `h : p` then `hn h : False` and `(hn h).elim` will prove anything. For more information: [Propositional Logic](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/propositions_and_proofs.html#propositional-logic).

de Moura, Leonardo, Mario Carneiro et al. “Init.Prelude.” Mathlib4 Docs. Accessed Feb 10, 2023. https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#Not.

We can solve the problem as follows:

```
theorem problem_2 : (p → ¬q) → ¬(p ∧ q) := by
  intro hpnq hpq
  have hp : p := hpq.1
  have hnq : ¬q := hpnq hp
  have hq : q := hpq.2  
  exact hnq hq
```

Comment: What does the hpq.1 mean?

Comment: @helpoatmeal If `h : a ∧ b`, then `h.left`, also notated as `h.1`, is shorthand for `And.left h : a`. For more information, see https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#And.